# VIM symbol ^A in log file

Tags: vim, control-characters

When I open a special log file (http://www.quickfixj.org/) in GVIM2, I get:

[image: GVIM2]

What does `^A` especially means and how can I search it (typing `/patternXY`)?

Thanks for your help!

Kind regards

P.S.: I am using VIM version 7.4 on OS Windows 7.

Comment: it's a literal "ctrl-a" character, ascii 0x01

Comment: with vim you can press ga in normal mode to show info about the char under the cursor. in this case vim show `<^A> 1, HEX 01, Octal 001`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try `:help digraph-table` in Vim, you can see

```
char  digraph   hex     dec     official name
^@      NU      0x00      0     NULL (NUL)
^A      SH      0x01      1     START OF HEADING (SOH)
...
```

So `^A` is the ASCII 0x01 character. If you want to see `^A` things with hex code, try `set display+=uhex`. It'll be displayed as `<01>` with color of gray.

Also you can search this character with <kbd>/</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>. See `:help i_CTRL-V`:

```
CTRL-V          Insert next non-digit literally.  For special keys, the
                terminal code is inserted.  It's also possible to enter the
                decimal, octal or hexadecimal value of a character
                i_CTRL-V_digit.
                The characters typed right after CTRL-V are not considered for
                mapping.  {Vi: no decimal byte entry}
                Note: When CTRL-V is mapped (e.g., to paste text) you can
                often use CTRL-Q instead i_CTRL-Q.
```

You can enter a character with its hex value, `<C-V>Xnn` or `<C-V>xnn`, or its decimal value, `<C-V>nnn`, or its octal value, `<C-V>Onnn` or `<C-V>onnn`. In this case, it'll be `<C-V>x01`, `<C-V>001`, or `<C-V>o001`.

If you're using Vim on Windows, `Ctrl-V` might be used to paste. Then try `Ctrl-Q` instead of `Ctrl-V`. See `:help CTRL-V-alternative`:

```
Since CTRL-V is used to paste, you can't use it to start a blockwise Visual
selection.  You can use CTRL-Q instead.  You can also use CTRL-Q in Insert
mode and Command-line mode to get the old meaning of CTRL-V.  But CTRL-Q
doesn't work for terminals when it's used for control flow.
```

Answer (score 3):

You can type it with `Ctrl-V` and then `Ctrl-A`. More generally, typing `Ctrl-V` allows you to literally type the next key (without being interpreted); try `Ctrl-V` and then `Return`.

Thus, you can search it with: `/`, then `Ctrl-V`, then `Ctrl-A`.